# How to make color picker stick/snap to certain values

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I will be creating a circular color picker something like this.
There will be 12 colors to pick from (**30 degrees per color**), and the pointer will be draggable.

I don't need detailed solution, just a guide on how to make the pointer draggable in that way, that if it is set between first and second colors (say 32 degrees) it should slide to 45 degrees (the middle of the second color) and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: When you drop your slider you should get a value from 0 to 360. So you simply divide it by 30 (degrees per color) then do Math.round() on result and then multiply it back by 30. You will get value like 0, 30, 60, 90 etc. that is closest to your input value. And if you want it to be in the middle (like 15, 45, 75 etc.) just subtract 15 at the begging and then add 15 to the end result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example function that I've mentioned in the comment:

```
function roundAngle(angle)
{
    return Math.round((angle-15)/30) * 30 + 15;
}
```

And here is an example in practice:
https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/k58z44kb/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob, it works just the way I needed it to.
Could you please also help me with the touch events, since I'm finding it hard to make it work.

Comment: Well if you want to use touches here you need to replace mouse events with respectively: `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend`. Also instead of using `e.clientX` you have to use `e.targetTouches[0].clientX` Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/k58z44kb/24/
However, I am not an expert in terms of touch events so I recommend learning about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events).